# mysql_fetch_array won't loop through all results

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I know we have to get off of the depreciated php mysql functions and move to mysqli or PDO.  However, that transition won't be happening here for a few weeks and I need to get this working like ASAP.

Basically, I have code that works fine on our old server (PHP 5.2.13), as well as smaller queries on our new server (PHP 5.4.20), but for larger queries will only return a partial record set and then just... die I guess?  What record it dies on depends on the query, but it pretty much always dies somewhere in the range of record 10k to 15k.  I suspect it is dying because of some kind of php.ini setting that sets a limit or something but I have no idea what it would be.  I've streamlined the code to the essentials here:

```
$query = $my_query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$record_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "Query has returned " . $record_count . " records.<br>";

$y=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "START";
    echo $y . " ";
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    { echo $value . " "; }
    $y=$y+1;

    echo "END" . "<br>";
}
echo "GOT OUT OF THERE!";
```

So yeah, the record_count will echo that the query returned about 250k records, but in the loop it basically will do somewhere between 10-15k records, echo the final "END", but then the loop just plain stops.  It doesn't get back to the next "START" nor does it ever get to the "GOT OUT OF THERE!"  And again, this same exact code works fine on our old server, as well as smaller queries on our new server.

Anyone have any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: How long before it dies? Consistently like 30 seconds?

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't thinking about time but yeah, it is probably consistent.  Somewhere around 15 seconds or so.

Comment: Check php.ini and tweak the `max_execution_time` value, or add a `set_time_limit()` with a higher value and see if that allows for more records to be returned. I wouldn't remove the time limit completely as it's there for a reason and mysql can really hang your server.

Comment: set_time_limit(0) added to the top of my file did not solve the issue.

Comment: You can also try to increase the memory limit or flush after xx records, 15K records in html might be too much for the default setting. For example `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");`

Comment: Ok, got it working... changed max_execution_time, max_input_time, and memory_limit to higher values in php.ini.  Not sure which one fixed it, going to test a bit to find out.  The weird thing though is I just checked the values on the old working server and they were the same as the values on this server that didn't work.

Comment: Ok... it was memory_limit that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just timing out. You can override the server's default timeout settings for an individual script by adding this line:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This will allow the script to run forever. If you want to set a different time limit, the parameter is in seconds, so for instance, this will allow the script to run for 5 minutes:

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

Comment: Add it to the top of the file?  Still having the issue.

Comment: But `$record_count` is returning the correct number of rows?

Comment: The next thing to check would be the memory limit. Ah, I see you're already on it.